# Lost All Privileges in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have seen this same question in many forms on this site and in many other forums.  However, I have tried all the solutions and still have the same outcome.  I'm pretty sure I once had root access on this MySQL server in the past and I was even able to use the phpMyAdmin tool to create databases amongst others queries.  Now when I go to phpMyAdmin and click on databases I am greeted by:

[image]

If I use the command tool I can login using:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get prompted to enter a password and I do so.  When I try to do anything else, say:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;

I get the following:
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

I have also followed this article ( http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/ ) since yes I am ssh'ing to this MySQL server from a remote machine.  Again, when I attempt:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

In various forms, I am greeted by a nasty:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Even though I am putting the same password I used to login!  I also want to mention that I updated my pear resources yesterday and I wonder if this was the cause of this mess...

If anyone can guide me, I'd truly appreciate it.  Thank you for all your time and consideration.

Elshae

****Update****
In trying to troubleshoot and running mysqld I now cannot start the server back up!  Every time I run:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

What should I do?

Comment: I forgot to say that I have also done:

mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWOR | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: How was your MySQL server installed/started? There's an option that makes it ignore grant tables at startup, but it has side effects like what you describe...

Comment: Ouch, unfortunately I didn't install it.  Is there anyway that I can get that information?  Also, I have stopped and started it before using commands /etc/init.d/mysql start/stop if that plays any part..

Comment: Sounds like you have this hosted through someone? Perhaps try contacting your provider and see if they can do anything?

Comment: No I have it hosted in house, I just didn't do the installation.  I have been given the task of basically being the admin, but I haven't been able to sort this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's feedback, I finally got it for the most part.  To combat the issue of

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

I did:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Which gave me:

```
root     15265  0.0  0.1   3896  1284 pts/10   S    12:41   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    15302  1.6  2.8 132532 29600 pts/10   Sl   12:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root     15303  0.0  0.0   3008   608 pts/10   S    12:41   0:00 logger -p daemon.err -t mysqld_safe -i -t mysqld
root     16160  0.0  0.0   3120   708 pts/10   R+   12:42   0:00 grep mysql
```

then I did:

```
kill -9 15265
kill -9 15302
```

After that I was able to start up MySQL with:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

From there I found this article:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset and the magic for me there was:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

I was able to follow the thread and also did:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yournewrootpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The only thing that's a bit strange is that the root still does not have the right to create databases from phpMyAdmin amongst other privileges that the root needs.  However, I am able to create databases from the command line and for now I can live with that!

Thanks again everyone for your time and all the help!

Answer (score 6):

Stop your MySQL service (UNIX style):

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Start your MySQL with privileges:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe  --skip-grant-tables
```

Connect to mysql DB with your root user

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p mysql
```

Update root privileges

```
update mysql.user
set Select_priv='Y',
    Insert_priv='Y',
    Update_priv='Y',
    Delete_priv='Y',
    Create_priv='Y',
    Drop_priv='Y',
    Reload_priv='Y',
    Shutdown_priv='Y',
    Process_priv='Y',
    File_priv='Y',
    Grant_priv='Y',
    References_priv='Y',
    Index_priv='Y',
    Alter_priv='Y',
    Show_db_priv='Y',
    Super_priv='Y',
    Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',
    Lock_tables_priv='Y',
    Execute_priv='Y',
    Repl_slave_priv='Y',
    Repl_client_priv='Y',
    Create_view_priv='Y',
    Show_view_priv='Y',
    Create_routine_priv='Y',
    Alter_routine_priv='Y',
    Create_user_priv='Y',
    Event_priv='Y',
    Trigger_priv='Y' 
where User='root';
```

After that, you just need to stop the MySQL service and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` will ONLY work if you are logged in as a user who have all rights...

As you don't have rights to `GRANT`, in your case above statement won't work... Please contact administrator and get ACCESS to connect...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have local access to the client, you might attempt to reset the root password with `mysqladmin`:

```
> mysqladmin password yournewrootpassword
```

If you can successfully login, it may then be necessary to grant root access once again before you can access any databases:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yournewrootpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get:


mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'